# Derive the quadrature rule of the form $\int_{-1}^1 f(x) dx \approx w_0 f(\alpha) + w_1 f'(\beta)$

Tags: numerical-methods, gaussian-integral, quadrature

From a practice problem

### Problem Statement

> Let the interval $[a,b]$ be divided into $n$ subintervals by $n+1$ points $x_0 = a , x_1 = a+h$, $x_2 = a+2h , \dots ,x_n = a+nh =b$. Derive the quadrature rule of the form
> $$
> \int_{-1}^1 f(x) \mathrm{d} x \approx w_0 f(\alpha) + w_1 f'(\beta) ,\quad -1 \le \alpha < \beta \le 1 \tag{1}
> ,$$
> that is exact for polynomials of as high degree as possible.

#### Attempt at solution

Let $p(x)$ be the lagrange interpolation polynomial interoplating the points $(x_0, f(x_0) ), \dots , (x_n , f(x_n))$. Then

$$
p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n l_i(x) f(x_i) \qquad \text{for} , \ l_i (x) = \prod_{j=0, j\neq i}^n \left( \frac{x-x_j}{x_i - x_j} \right)
$$
it follows that
$$
\int_{-1}^1 f(x) \mathrm{d} x \approx \int_{-1}^1 p(x) \mathrm{d} x 
$$
where
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1 p(x) \mathrm{d} x &= \int_{-1}^1 \sum_{i=0}^n l_i(x) f(x_i) \mathrm{d} x \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^n \left( \int_{-1}^1 l_i(x) \mathrm{d} x \right) f(x_i) \mathrm{d} x \\
&:= \sum_{i=0}^n w_i f(x_i)
\end{align}
We conclude
$$
\therefore \int_{-1}^1 f(x) \mathrm{d} x = \sum_{i=0}^n w_i f(x_i) 
$$

---

### Questions

From here I am stuck. In $(1)$ we have a function derivative $f'(\beta)$, but in the formula derived above, there's no such thing. Moreover, I don't know how many terms in this sum to take as well. Does anyone know how I can complete this derivation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference to the sub-intervals is useless... We just want to determine the quadrature nodes ($\alpha, \beta)$ and weights ($\omega_0, \omega_1$) that make the rule exact for polynomial of degree as high as possible. So, forcing the rule to be exact for $f(x)=1, f(x) = x, f(x)=x^2, \cdots$, you get a system of equations that allows the calculation of $\alpha, \beta, \omega_0, \omega_1$:

$$
\omega_0 \cdot 1 + \omega_1 \cdot 0 = 2 \Leftrightarrow \omega_0=2
$$

$$
\omega_0 \cdot \alpha + \omega_1 \cdot 1 = 0\Leftrightarrow 2 \alpha+\omega_1=0
$$

$$
\omega_0 \alpha^2 + \omega_1 \cdot 2 \beta = \frac 23
$$

$$
\vdots
$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already did all of that, but the problem statement asks to derive the quadrature rule, does that mean I just need to find the coefficients $w_0,w_1,\alpha,\beta$ ? I thought I must go through some derivation to arrive at the integral in the form that it is given, don't I?

Comment: @hexaquark the definition of the quadrature rule just involves $\alpha, \beta, \omega_0, \omega_1$... It does not make any sense to mention or even consider the subdivisions of the interval.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the term $f'(\beta)$ is involved in the error term $R_{n+1}(x)$ of the approximating polynomial.
To make the quadrature formula exact, the error term should vanish, i.e.,  $f'(\beta)=0$. This is possible for all $f$ if $f$ is a constant function.
So let assume $f(x)=1$. Then the formula $\int_{-1}^1 f(x) \mathrm{d} x \approx w_0 f(\alpha) + w_1 f'(\beta)$ gives
$w_0=2\tag{1}$
But if $f$ is a linear function or of degree higher than $1$, then the formula contains some error and we can get for $f(x)=x$ using the formula $\int_{-1}^1 f(x) \mathrm{d} x \approx w_0 f(\alpha) + w_1 f'(\beta)$,
$w_0.\alpha+w_1=0\tag{2}$
Similarly for the functions $f(x)=x^2,x^3$, we get
$w_0.\alpha^2+2w_1.\beta=\dfrac 23\tag{3}$
and
$w_0.\alpha^3+3w_1.\beta^2=0\tag{4}$
Above four equations give the required quadrature.